# Map <Leader>s to file structure popup, works but immediately disappears

Tags: android-studio, ideavim

I've mapped `<Leader>s` to `:action FileStructurePopup<CR>` in my .ideavimrc file.  The mapping works but the popup is immediately cancelled.  How can I get it to stay?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in [VIM-1016](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1016), but the fix hasn't been released yet. You can download and install a CI build that contains the fix, see https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim.